# Reiniciar ComboBox a su estado por defecto

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un `JFrame` que ingrese en un `JTextField` los valores de un `JComboBox` y cada vez que ingrese los valores, la opción seleccionada desaparezca para que así el usuario no pueda volver a seleccionarla. Esto funciona correctamente.

Pero también quiero realizar, que a la hora de darle a un botón, se reinicia a sus valores por "defecto". Pero no se como podría hacer que el `JComboBox` vuelva a la "normalidad".

He intentado `removeAllItems()` para poder eliminar todas las opciones que queden y luego intentar añadirlas, pero no funciona nada de lo que hago.

```java
public class combobox extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form combobox
     */
    public combobox() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        opc1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        opc2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        opc3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        seleccion = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        Reiniciar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        seleccion.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Opcion 1", "Opcion 2", "Opcion 3", "Opcion 4" }));
        seleccion.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                seleccionActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Reiniciar.setText("Reiniciar");
        Reiniciar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ReiniciarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(seleccion, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(opc1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(opc2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(opc3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(Reiniciar)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(opc1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(opc2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(opc3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(seleccion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 19, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(Reiniciar)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void seleccionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String opciones = (String) seleccion.getSelectedItem();

        String caja1 = opc1.getText().trim();
        String caja2 = opc2.getText().trim();
        String caja3 = opc3.getText().trim();

        switch(opciones){
            case "Opcion 1":
                opciones = "Opcion 1";
                seleccion.removeItemAt(0);
                break;
            case "Opcion 2":
                opciones = "Opcion 2";
                seleccion.removeItemAt(1);
                break;
            case "Opcion 3":
                opciones = "Opcion 3";
                seleccion.removeItemAt(2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if( caja1.isEmpty() ){
            opc1.setText(opciones);
        }else if( caja2.isEmpty() ){
            opc2.setText(opciones);
        }else if( caja3.isEmpty()){
            opc3.setText(opciones);
        }
    }                                         

    private void ReiniciarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(combobox.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(combobox.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(combobox.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(combobox.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new combobox().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Reiniciar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField opc1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField opc2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField opc3;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> seleccion;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... y cada vez que ingrese los valores, la opción seleccionada desaparezca para que así el usuario no pueda volver a seleccionarla. Esto funciona correctamente.

**Primero algo importante**; no funciona correctamente ya que fallaria al estar referenciando con un valor constante que no coincide con el indice del item y/o mostraria en el `JTextField` el item equivocado; me explico:

Al tener `seleccion.removeItemAt(0);` en efecto se elimina esa opción y lógicamente el vector cambia de tamaño, se reduce, si por consiguiente la instrucción `seleccion.removeItemAt(3);` se ejecuta, de una vez salta un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Entonces para no trabajar con ese valor *hardcodeado* es conveniente implementar el método [`getSelectedIndex()`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/11/latestSpec/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex()):

```
switch(opciones){
  case "Opcion 1":
    opciones = "Opcion 1";
    //seleccion.removeItemAt(0);
    seleccion.removeItemAt(seleccion.getSelectedIndex());
  break;
  case "Opcion 2":
    opciones = "Opcion 2";
    //seleccion.removeItemAt(1);
    seleccion.removeItemAt(seleccion.getSelectedIndex());
  break;
  case "Opcion 3":
    opciones = "Opcion 3";
    //seleccion.removeItemAt(2);
    seleccion.removeItemAt(seleccion.getSelectedIndex());
  break;
  default:
  break;
}
```

Ahora, si nos damos cuenta en el código se ve que sin importar cual opción del `switch` coincida siempre ira a correr la misma instrucción, lo que nos sugiere que perfectamente podemos deshacernos de este `switch` y quedarnos con la simple linea del `getSelectedIndex()`:

```
private void seleccionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  // TODO add your handling code here:
  String opciones = (String) seleccion.getSelectedItem();
  String caja1 = opc1.getText().trim();
  String caja2 = opc2.getText().trim();
  String caja3 = opc3.getText().trim();

  seleccion.removeItemAt(seleccion.getSelectedIndex());

  if( caja1.isEmpty() ){
    opc1.setText(opciones);
  }else if( caja2.isEmpty() ){
    opc2.setText(opciones);
  }else if( caja3.isEmpty()){
    opc3.setText(opciones);
  }
}
```

Finalmente la respuesta a tu duda está en el código :D
*resetear* el `JComboBox` a través del modelo:

```
private void ReiniciarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  // TODO add your handling code here:
  seleccion.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Opcion 1", "Opcion 2", "Opcion 3", "Opcion 4" }));
  opc1.setText("");
  opc2.setText("");
  opc3.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!